# Creating a fadeIn effect

Tags: html5-canvas

I'm trying to create a  slideshow using a canvas element, which is working well. By clicking on next you'll see another picture.
I wanna add an fadeIn effect that goes from left to right when the next picture is shown, but i have no idea how to do that.
All things I tried didn't work.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `globalAlpha` method. By changing this value (between 0 and 1) you can change the alpha value of the canvas context:

```
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5; // half faded
```

Using a variable to increase/decrease the value each loop, you can create a fade in/out effect.